# how to align items in the center and right

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child center"> </div>
  <div class="child"> </div>
  <div class="child"> </div>
</div>
```

[image]

and this is what i've got.

It seems the black one is located in the a little left, not the "center" of the parent.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Would you want the three elements to still stack in smaller screens where there is limited space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using `grid` instead of `flexbox`, you can utilize the property `justify-self` to align the black box to the center with the help of `position: absolute;`. The absolute positioning here makes it so it's possible to align the black box toward the center without minding/affecting the other two boxes. See the snippet below:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.center {
  background-color: black;
  justify-self: center;
  position: absolute;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .center {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child center"> </div>
  <div class="child"> </div>
  <div class="child"> </div>
</div>
```

*PS. I've added a `@media` query in case you want the 3 boxes to stack on a smaller space/screen.*

Edit: Changed display on smaller screens and applied wrapping when necessary using `flex-wrap`.

More on `justify-self` and `grid` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) respectively.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Could i also wrap the black one and the gray ones when the screen shrinks? like ```flex-wrap: wrap```  on the parent

Comment: @YOY edited the snippet to enable wrapping. You can check the changes above.

Comment: That's what i exactly wanted. you added ```display:flex; flex:wrap:wrap;``` in ```@media``` query. Thank you for sharing again!