# How to align an Textarea in the middle of the webpage

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hi Guys I've been trying to figure out how to sit my textarea in the middle of the webpage and sit next to my other textarea that's on the left side of the screen. Code below! i would very much appreciate it, if I could get 2 different ways i could have approached this plz.

```css
body {
  background-color: #434343;
}

#textFields {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 550px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea name="Buy" id="advertise" cols="30" rows="50"></textarea>

  <div id="textFields">
    <textarea name="" class="center" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <textarea name="" class="center" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <textarea name="" class="center" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use floats to align your content, especially if you are already using flex. Just nest your code in a `wrapper` and define a height and width. You can set `display: flex;` on that wrapper. I wouldn't use a fixed margin to space your flex-items as it is very unresponsive.

Just change `justify-content: center;` to either `justify-content: space-around;` or `justify-content: space-evenly;` which basically do the same thing to space your flex-items.

*Edit* ~ Removed `justify-content: center;` and added `margin: 0 auto;` to `#textFields` per OP questions in comments.

```css
body {
  background-color: #434343;
}

#textFields {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea name="Buy" id="advertise" cols="30" rows="50"></textarea>

  <div id="textFields">
    <textarea name="" class="center" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <textarea name="" class="center" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <textarea name="" class="center" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: okay, i understand what you did! But I want the larger textbox to stay on the left side of the screen. While the other 3 are in the middle.

Comment: @HanifKillMongerGibson easy fix. Remove `justify-content: center;` and add `margin: 0 auto;` to `#textFields`. The 0 means 0 margin on top and bottom and auto left and right. Hence, why it is centered now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flexbox` to get the layout that you want. And to center the three other `textarea`s without affecting the center layout of the `#textfield` then you can use positioning. You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71043638/how-to-align-items-in-the-center-and-right/71043900#71043900) as well. See the snippet below:

```css
body {
  background-color: #434343;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.leftField{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

#textFields {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#textFields>textarea {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea class="leftField"></textarea>
  <div id="textFields">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

More on `flexbox` and `positions` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) respectively.

Comment: Thanks bro! my knowledge on flex box isn't great!

Comment: You can check the link that I included above to learn more about it! :)

Comment: I think the OP has accepted the answer, if he had something more to add, he can do so himself in the comments.

Comment: @カメロン Uhh... ok?

Comment: @HanifKillMongerGibson if you want to really center the `#texfield` in your webpage without it being affected by the other `textarea` to the right, then you can use `position`ings. I've edited the snippet above. It might be what you need.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a floating attribute on the first text field element.

```
<div style="float:left">
  <textarea name="Buy" id="advertise" cols="30" rows="50"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: wow I didn't think to use float left.

Comment: you shouldn't be using floats in the year 2022

Comment: @Pixelomo why is that? if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @HanifKillMongerGibson Before flex-box and grid, float was the go-to. But with the power of flex and grid (if done correctly), there is no need. You can read more here: [Is CSS float deprecated? | CSS-Tricks - CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/is-css-float-deprecated/)

Comment: @HanifKillMongerGibson float can often lead to cross-browser bugs, flex-box is the bullet-proof, modern solution

Comment: @Pixelomo Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I appreciate it a lot!